# How can I get the URL paramter dynamically in Java?

Tags: java, http, url, jakarta-ee, request

A url is hit from browser now I want to get that url in my dataBean to extract its parameters for some checks.

How can I get that URL dynamically in that particular databean?

for instance :
someone hit

```
https://someAddress/AjaxForm?id=someid
```

I need to capture this url and get value of Id. How to do it?

Comment: you should give us a snippet of your code at least the method and describe  what class is that method in to help you

Comment: @achabahe I actually haven't written code related to this specific scenario as I got no idea how to do it, I wrote the code that needs to be executed after getting url, using hard coded url but getting no idea how to get browser url in Java bean, though I have successfully done same thing in javascript few days back but is confused in Java Bean.

Comment: can you show me the class to see how you can get  it there because if you are using servlet it is a piece of cake just one line code if you are using something else tell us what is it and we will help you get what you want i will post an answer how your servlet should look like if it is not what you want help us with some explanation

Answer (score 0):

you can do something likewise,

```
request.getRequestURL() // gives your current URL
```

where `request` is an instance of `HttpServletRequest`.

**UPDATED :**

If you are trying to find parameter which are comes along with `URL`, then

rather then do above mentioned my trick,

directly do likewise,

```
request.getParameter("id");
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, i actually have problem in initiating request variable, how to initiate it with current url data? I am using "getHttpRequest()" but it returns null.

Comment: i am under impression that you are using servlet, if you are using servlet then you will get it into your service-method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String url=request.getRequestURL()
    String id=request.getParameter("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the parameter from url

```
request.getParameter("id");
```

And to insert it, in javascript add the parameter by attaching it to url

```
var url=baseurl+"?id="+id;
```

Answer (score 0):

in the doGET method you write

```
String idValue=request.getParameter("id");
```

so the method will look like this

```
protected void doGET(HTTPServletRequest request,HTTPServletResponse response){
  //some code here
  String idValue=request.getParameter("id");//idValue will hold the value you passed in URL
  //some more code here
 }
```